# load c++ so file with static member from python issue

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have the following cpp code taken from geeksforgeeks web:

```
#include <iostream>
class Geek{

public:
    static int i;

    void myFunction(){
            
        (Geek::i)++;
        std::cout << "Hello Geek!!!" << Geek::i << std::endl;
    }
};
 int Geek::i=0;
  int main()
{
// Creating an object
Geek t; 

// Calling function
t.myFunction();  

return 0;
}

extern "C" {
Geek* Geek_new(){ return new Geek(); }
void Geek_myFunction(Geek* geek){ geek -> myFunction(); }
}
```

i've compiled it and create so file using the following commands:
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  foo.o

and called the so file from the python part:

```
# import the module
from ctypes import cdll

# load the library
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

# create a Geek class
class Geek(object):

# constructor
def __init__(self):

    # attribute
    self.obj = lib.Geek_new()
    self.obj2 = lib.Geek_new()

# define method
def myFunction(self):
    lib.Geek_myFunction(self.obj)
    lib.Geek_myFunction(self.obj2)

# create a Geek class object
f = Geek()

# object method calling
f.myFunction()
f.myFunction()
```

when i run this code i'm getting the following error:
./libfoo.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4Geek1iE

if i place the static variable inside my function and compile it, it works fine, but i need the variable to be a static member of the class.

what needs to be done to make it work?

**UPDATE**
i've update the code according to *tevemadar*, and it worked.
i needed to initialize GEEK::i outside the class

Comment: I don't see the `int Geek::i;` line. My C++ is a bit aged, but it still seems to be necessary: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: The elusive part here is that you are compiling a *library*, which doesn't have to be complete in itself, missing parts could come from other compilation units. Just they didn't, and that's how it becomes a runtime error instead.

Comment: thank you all for replying, i've updated my question accordng to tevemadar answer and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *tevemadar* for his answer.
we as `GEEK::i` and not just `i` in the class.
and initialize it outside the class

```
int GEEK::i = 0;
```

updated code can be seen in the question

Comment: Updating the question invalidates the question. Just post the correction in the answer